# Calculate numbers used from a sequence

Tags: algorithm, sequence

I got the following sequence of numbers 1,2,4,8,16,32,64....8192 - where each of the numbers represent something, like 1 could represent "Milk", and 2 could represent "Egg".

I got a cupcake with the value of 3. Since 1 + 2 = 3, I know that my cupcake contains both milk(1) and eggs(2).

However - I'm looking for an algorithm to help me achieve this. If the sum is 1536 I would like the algorithm to find 1024 and 512 - or, if the sum is 7 - numbers used would be: 1,2,4.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Do you know what binary is ?

Comment: Aware of binary, never programmed much with it though. Do you have any examples I could use that would point me in the right direction for solving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see if I understood, you have a sequence that is basically "binary" (power of 2) values, ex:

32---16---8----4----2-----1

0----0----0----1----1-----0     is 6

So you can go ahead and convert your input number (which is an int) to binary and then go bit by bit checking if they are turned on.

So lets say you have the number 35, to binary:

32---16---8----4----2-----1

1----0----0----0----1-----1

I will go bit by bit now

- Bit index 1 is turned on, so I have 1!
- Bit index 2 is turned on, so I have 2!
- Bit index 3 is turned off, skip!
- Bit index 4 is turned off, skip!
- Bit index 5 is turned off, skip!
- Bit index 6 is turned on, I have 32!

Result: 1 + 2 + 32 = 35

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: @MOehm Could you please explain how hard and crucial is to check bit by bit when you already have the binary representation of the integer? If you said I didn't provide with the algorithm to convert from integer to binary, I could agree (but IMO there is no need to add that to the answer).

Comment: @MOehm Oh! By the way, there is an option here in StackOverflow were you can improve an answer. You can go ahead and use it :)!

Comment: We don't have the binary representation, do we? The OP didn't realise that the problem was essentially a binary number.

Comment: @MOehm please go ahead and reread my answer, it clearly states: "you have a sequence that is basically "binary" (power of 2) values" and "So you can go ahead and convert your input number (which is an int) to binary". I even went ahead and made little "binary" table for him, what else can I make so it's clear for you and him that I'm talking about binary? Again, you can use the edit option and improve my answer whenever you want.

Comment: The binary table is useful if you want to find the bits with pencil and paper. The OP wants to find the bits with a computer, so a hint about how you can determine that a certain bit is set, for example with bitwise operators, would be helpful. Anyway, don't get worked up about my comment. I just thought that your answer wasn't very useful to the OP as is.

Comment: Didn't realize until now that binary would suffice... Thanks for making that clear. 

M Oehm, I see your point - but I'm able to check which bit is turned on and off by programming - just couldn't wrap my head around how to programmatically check how e.g. 9 had to be a result of 1 and 8.

Answer (score 1):

In a modern computer, integers are already represented in binary. You can take advantage of that by using [bitwise operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) (pseudocode):

```
for p := 30 downto 0:
    if (x and (1 shl p)) > 0:
        output (1 shl p)
```

For example, given x = 100<sub>10</sub> = 1100100<sub>2</sub>, the program will output 64, 32 and 4.

Here, `shl` is a [shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Arithmetic_shift) operation and `and` is [bitwise AND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND).

Answer (score 0):

You could continue taking the log base 2 of the number until you reach a number evenly divisible by 2^(log base 2 of that number)

Example:

- 1536
- log_2(1536) = 10 (so, add 2<sup>10</sup> = 1024 to your list)
- remainder = 1536 - 1024 = 512
- log_2(512) = 9 (so, add 2<sup>9</sup> = 512 to your list)
- remainder = 512 - 512 = 0
- so your list contains 1024 and 512

Working Python:

```py
import math
goal = int(raw_input("Enter a goal"))
solution = []
while(goal > 0):
    nextExponent = int(math.log(goal)/math.log(2))
    goal -= 2**nextExponent
    solution.append(2**nextExponent)
print solution
```

If your set of powers of 2 is limited, you will have to cap `nextExponent` at the maximum.

Sample input:

> Enter a goal 58094

Output:

> [32768, 16384, 8192, 512, 128, 64, 32, 8, 4, 2]